# Core Data migration when there's two identical model versions

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have a managed object model, which contains only one entity, `Person`. At model version 1, `Person` had the `id` and the `name` attribute. At version 2, I added the `phone` attribute and incremented each person’s `id` using a custom mapping model. Later I created version 3 removing the `phone` attribute. Here version 1 and version 3 are accidentally identical as illustrated below:

```
MOM ver  | v1        | v2        | v3
---------+-----------+-----------+-----------
Entity   | Person    | Person    | Person
Attrs    |   - id    |   - id    |   - id
         |   - name  |   - name  |   - name
         |           |   - phone |


              |        ^      |       ^
              `--------'      `-------'
Mapping:    * Add phone       * Remove phone
            * Increment id
```

With this model, a store created for model version 1 has the exactly the same schema as version 3. It can't be determined if the user has an older version of store which requires migration with necessary side effects or has the latest version.

So here's my question: how do I tell that a store is older enough for migration when I have two identical model versions? Maybe by putting a piece of version information in the store, but how and what info? Or should I be very careful not to create such versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add a new model version each time, right ?
Each of your models should have a unique model identifier. Select an .xcdatamodel in your data model and the id will show up under Core Data Model in Interface Builder. 
I like to give them IDs like 1.0, 2.0... corresponding to the actual app version.

This is a string, you can check in code if migration is needed or other stuff you need :

`[[[self objectModel] versionIdentifiers] anyObject]`